# Double 者 (read もの) in a compound sentence

Tags: manga

While reading manga of 進撃の巨人, we stumbled upon a compound sentence having 者 mentioned twice, both marked with は and at the end of that sentence. While we managed to understand (at least in our opinion, which seems to align with translations to the manga online) the sentence, we didn't understand why the second 者 is there.
Here is the manga panel for context and reference:
[image]

Just wanted to clear things although we think we managed to understand the general translation of that sentence. Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can just translate the sentence quite literally, with 者 being "the one":

> それを見た**者**は、この世界で一番の　自由を手に入れた**者**。
> **The one** who saw that was **the one** who got the utmost freedom of this world into his hands.

There are no rules stating that 者 cannot be used more than once in a sentence, just like in English there is no limit on "the one".

> both marked with は and at the end of that sentence

I only see one は here. If you meant the "これが" on the bottom, that's just another sentence. I don't know if anything comes after これが, but it's not a part of the previous sentence.

Comment: +1. According to [this](https://twitter.com/moru_shingeki/status/1347533753669730306), これが ("This is the...") is part of "これが自由だ".

Comment: @dvx2718 thank you for the detailed answer! I didn’t mean that both instances are marked with は, that was a poor choice of words on my part I’m sorry. And yes, the rest in another sentence - これが自由だ.

Comment: Although, I’m not sure about how the 者 can come after the verb in the sentence (grammatically). Is there any grammatical explanation to that?

Comment: @OrelVaknin Because in Japanese, relative clause comes before the noun to modify the noun. "A person who sees an apple" is "りんごを見る人", with the part "りんごを見る" coming before the noun. Please refer to [this answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/94396/39855) for more details. Additionally you may find this [article of grammar guide](https://guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/clause) helpful.

Comment: @dvx2718 thank you! That was really helpful